# Javascript/JQuery- Highlighting one link at a time on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some links I'd like to be highlighted when you select them, but only one at a time. I found this JQuery code, however, I can't get it to work. The links won't highlight even when I click it. I had a really straight forward Javascript function that changed the color of the link with the onlick. But I would like for it to only highlight the most recently clicked link.

The new JQuery is presented in the code, it appears like it should work I just don't know why it's not.  The Javascript function, selectedLink(), I used to call on the onlick method.  I'm willing to use either or, I just want the functionality.

```
 .highlight {
   color: #3385D6;
   border: 1px solid;
   border-color: #BBBBBB;
   background:#70AAE2;
   font-weight: bold;
  }

 function selectedLink(id){
  var sublink = document.getElementById(id);  
      sublink.style.background = "#CCCCCC";
      sublink.style.color = "#3385D6";
      sublink.style.fontWeight = "bold";        
      sublink.style.border = "1px solid";
      sublink.style.borderColor = "#BBBBBB";
        }
<input type="radio" name="UItab" id="tabf" >
<label for="tabf"><span>Menu Item</span></label>
   <div>
    <div>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
        <a href="#"><li id="">SecondLevel A</li></a></td>
        <a href="#" onclick="toggle('togglebox');"><li id="">SecondLevel B</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li id="">SecondLevel C</li></a>                    
        </ul>
    </div>
        <div id="togglebox">
                            <a href="#"><li id="">ThirdLevel A</li></a>
                            <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('barbox');"><li id="">ThirdLevel B</li></a>
                            <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('piebox');"><li id="">ThirdLevel C</li></a>                      
        </div>  
                <div id="barbox">
                        <a  href="#"><li id="">Fourth Level A</li></a>
                        <a  href="#"><li id="">Fourth Level B</li></a>
                        <a  href="#"><li id="">Fourth Level C</li></a>                  
                </div>
               <div id="piebox">
                        <a  href="#"><li id="">Fourth Level A</li></a>
                        <a  href="#"><li id="">Fourth Level B</li></a>
                        <a  href="#"><li id="">Fourth Level C</li></a>                  
                </div>
<script>
$('a').click(
function(e){
e.preventDefault;
$('.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
$(this).addClass('highlight')
});
</script>
```

Comment: show us your js code

Comment: actually your code just runs fine.. I think the issue is with the place you are putting the javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code is fine just wrap around a `$(function(){/*here*/});`

```js
$(function () {
    $('a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
        $(e.target).addClass('highlight');
    });
});

function selectedLink(id) {
    var sublink = document.getElementById(id);
    sublink.style.background = "#CCCCCC";
    sublink.style.color = "#3385D6";
    sublink.style.fontWeight = "bold";
    sublink.style.border = "1px solid";
    sublink.style.borderColor = "#BBBBBB";
}

function toggle_visibility(s) {}
```

```css
.highlight {
    color: #3385D6;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #BBBBBB;
    background:#70AAE2;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="UItab" id="tabf" >
<label for="tabf"><span>Menu Item</span></label>
<div>
<div>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
 <a href="#"><li id="">SecondLevel A</li></a>
 <a href="#" onclick="toggle('togglebox');"><li id="">SecondLevel B</li></a>
 <a href="#"><li id="">SecondLevel C</li></a>                    
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="togglebox">
  <a href="#"><li id="">ThirdLevel A</li></a>
  <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('barbox');"><li id="">ThirdLevel B</li></a>
  <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('piebox');"><li id="">ThirdLevel C</li></a>
  <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('linebox');"><li id="">ThirdLevel D</li></a>
  <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('tablebox');"><li id="">ThirdLevel E</li></a>
  <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('gaugebox');"><li id="">ThirdLevel F</li></a>

</div>  
<div id="barbox">
  <a  href="#"><li id="">Fourth Level A</li></a>
  <a  href="#"><li id="">Fourth Level B</li></a>
  <a  href="#"><li id="">Fourth Level C</li></a>                  
</div>
```

Comment: It's really nested within a bunch of divs and i think this may be the case of why it's not working. Is there a different way I should call it?

Comment: please provide us the whole HTML structure in a JS fiddle

Comment: I edited my code in the question with the HTML structure. I can't get a JS Fiddle to function correctly.

Comment: Check out new code it worked fine just with a problem your code that a `</td>` was extra in your html that was not working remove that all is good

Answer (score 0):

instead of removing class to .highlight, remove class for all a elements

```
$(a).removeClass('highlight');
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the solution but it looks like you should use `e.preventDefault()` instead of `e.preventDefault`

Comment: If it is not the answer, put this as a comment.

Comment: this could just be the answer.

Comment: @tibzon Not enough rep to comment on the question itself + it may be (part of) the solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('a').click(
    function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('highlight').siblings().removeClass('highlight');
});
```

Comment: It's really nested within a bunch of divs and i think this may be the case of why it's not working. Is there a different way I should call it?

Comment: I tried this way. Seems to work. What is the problem you are facing ?

Comment: I got it to work. I was leaving out a script source. Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

may be this will work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('a').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            //All a tag having class highlight
            $('a.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
            $(this).addClass('highlight');
        });
    });
```

Comment: It's really nested within a bunch of divs and i think this may be the case of why it's not working. Is there a different way I should call it?